# How to run pgBouncer in heroku.yml with daphne

Tags: docker, heroku, pgbouncer, daphne

So I built a chat app and deployed it with heroku. Since I'm on hobby-dev I can only have 20 connections to postgres, so following some suggestions online I decided using pgbouncer may be a good idea. The heroku document on setting the buildpack up (for example, last part of https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections#number-of-active-connections) are limited and everything I found asked me to change something in the Procfile. The problem is that I was using a docker container and thus ended up using heroku.yml and a daphne command to run the program. Directly adding `bin/start-pgbouncer` in web simply cause the entire application to fail.

This is my current run command

```
run:
  web: daphne test_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

I tried

```
run:
  web: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel daphne test_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

and

```
run:
  web: start-pgbouncer-stunnel daphne test_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

Both failed. I also found out on heroku logs that heroku seems to automatically append `/bin/sh -c` to my run command (ex, `/bin/sh -c daphne\ test_project.asgi:application\ --port\ \53166\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0\ -v2`).

Could this be causing the problem? What should I put in web to run pg-bouncer alongside my app?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem, or a way to close the connections in daphne?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this is to create a bash script `run.sh`.

```sh
set -ev

service pgbouncer start
daphne test_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
service pgbouncer stop
```

```
run:
  web: run.sh
```